# Explicit examples of manifolds with different signatures (mod 16)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds

If I understand correctly, one easy way to construct the arbitrary [signature $\sigma(M)$ of 4-manifold $M$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_(topology)) is by connecting sum the $\mathbf{CP}^2$ manifolds, since $\sigma(\mathbf{CP}^2)=1$.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\sigma(M)& -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7    \\ 
\hline
M & \overline{(\mathbf{CP}^2)^{\#2}} & \overline{\mathbf{CP}^2} & S^p \times S^q \times S^m \times  \dots & \mathbf{CP}^2 & \mathbf{CP}^2 \# \mathbf{CP}^2 & (\mathbf{CP}^2)^{\#3} & (\mathbf{CP}^2)^{\#4} & (\mathbf{CP}^2)^{\#5} &  &   \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\sigma(M)&  8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15   \\ 
\hline
M &  \dots &  \dots &  \dots &  \dots &  \dots &  \dots &  \dots &  \dots   \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

I also understand that the product spaces of spheres have $$\sigma(S^p \times S^q \times S^m \times  \dots)=0.$$

What are other ways to construct $M$ with $\sigma(M)$ for arbitrary integers?

I am looking for explicit examples of manifolds with different signatures.

All spin 4-manifolds have $\sigma(M) =0$ (mod 16). So we are looking into some non-spin 4-manifolds.

Comment: I'm confused about whether your question is about manifolds or $4$-manifolds in particular. You write $\mathbb{CP}^1$ when you mean $\mathbb{CP}^2$; $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is a $2$-manifold so its signature is $0$. Your claim about the signature of a product of spheres is also incorrect; all such products have signature $0$, because spheres are boundaries.

Comment: yes I corrected. You are correct it is $CP^2$. A typo

Comment: Yes that was another typo $\sigma(S^p \times S^q \times S^m \times  \dots)=0.$